# How I can configure properties file right?

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I have maven project with several modules

this is part of database-config.xml in office-core module:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="locations">
             <list>
                   <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
             </list>
      </property>
</bean>
```

I have application.properties files on several places:

c:\projects\office\app\office-core\application.properties

c:\projects\office\app\office-core\src\main\profiles\application.properties

c:\projects\office\app\application.properties

In my opinion with this config in database-config.xml I should can use the properties file in my database-config.xml 
but I cant... Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the `application.properties` file to `src/main/resources` directory to have it effectively on classpath. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will not work because those paths are not part of your classpath. I suggest you to have some default configuration and to have configuration override per module, something like that:

```
<bean id="overrideConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="file:/SomeFolderInFileSystem/conf.properties"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
</bean>
```